# How to fill in gaps of duplicate indices in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('AAAD'),size=(5)),
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('PPPS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWRR'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

I am trying to create a multi-index dataframe using some of the input columns

So, I tried the below

```
tdf.set_index(['grade','dumeel'],inplace=True)
```

However, this results in missing/gap for duplicate entries (in red highlight)

[image]

How can I avoid that and show my dataframe with all indices (whether it is duplicate or not)

I would like to my output to have all rows with corresponding indices based on original dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only display issue:

```
tdf.set_index(['grade','dumeel'],inplace=True)

print (tdf)
             dash  dumma  target
grade dumeel                    
A     W         S    855       1
      R         P    498       1
      R         P    378       0
      W         P    211       0
      W         P     12       0
      
with pd.option_context("display.multi_sparse", False):
    print (tdf)
             dash  dumma  target
grade dumeel                    
A     W         S    855       1
A     R         P    498       1
A     R         P    378       0
A     W         P    211       0
A     W         P     12       0
```